# How to return a list from __repr__ in a class?

Tags: python, object, repr

I am trying the project from here: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/deck-of-cards/7
I want the instance to be a associated as a list.
My code looks like this:

```
from card import Card


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = []
        self.populate()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._cards


    def populate(self):
        suits = ["diamonds", "clubs", "spades", "hearts"]
        numbers = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
        cards = []
        for suit in suits:
            for number in numbers:
                cards.append(Card(suit, number))
        self._cards = cards

    def shuffle(self):
        pass



my_deck = Deck()
print(my_deck)
```

I am new to objects, and programming in general. Please be as layman as possible.

Comment: The `__repr__()` method is defined by the Python language to return a string with a representation of the associated object in it — you can only change what's in the string, not the method's return type.

Comment: `__repr__` returns a `str`, not a `list`, period.

Comment: You *cannot* return a list from `.__repr__()` - the whole point of that method is to return a string representation of your object.  You could perhaps return a string version of a list - `return repr(self._cards)`.

Comment: I suggest you add an `as_list()` method to the class that does what you want.

Comment: Or you know, rename `_cards` to `cards` without the underscore to make it a "public" attribute.